# Angular Material Time Picker 24 Hours

Tags: javascript, angular, material-ui, angular14

I have an application built with Angular 14 and Material UI, and I am currently facing difficulty in finding a time picker component that supports the 24-hour format.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [ngx-material-timepicker / Angular Material Timepicker](https://github.com/Agranom/ngx-material-timepicker):

Here's an example from the [official demo](https://agranom.github.io/ngx-material-timepicker/).

We need to set the `[format]="24"`.

```html
<div class="24hr-example">
  <input
    aria-label="24hr format"
    placeholder="24hr format"
    readonly
    [format]="24"
    [ngxTimepicker]="fullTime"
  />
  <ngx-material-timepicker #fullTime></ngx-material-timepicker>
</div>
```